# PHPUnit uncategorized option --run

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I have currently installed PHPUnit locally in my project, when I try to run the tests in terminal on my server I see the tests are ran successfully, however when I try to run the tests in my IDE I get this output:

> "E:\Programs\php\php.exe" "E:\www\dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit"
>   "--colors" "--log-junit"
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap"
>   "E:\www\dev\vendor\autoload.php" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   8.0.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=E:\www\dev\tests\Project\models\Users\UserTest.php"
>   PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> unrecognized option --run
>   Done.

If I try to enter `--run` argument in the terminal I get the same message.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in Dev builds, you can try them from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/)

For more details see [issue #254276](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254276)